# JMeter - 1 account simulates 100 users to Login Website

Tags: jmeter

I'm having a problem with JMeter result.
I only use 1 account (username/password) simulates 100 users (Thread group > Number of Threads : 100).
My scenario is: 
100 users login to a website at same time (Ramp up: 1) > After login successful, I add a Response Assertion to make sure that I'm at Home page.
Result: All Pass, but I notice that a lot of users were moved to Login page (Fail).
I wonder if my Load test scenario was right or not?
Do I have to create 100 accounts and use CSV Configuration to make sure that all 100 users are logged in successful?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think you need to create multiple accounts. But, I would require more details to help you.

Comment: The problem is: when I set Number of thread = 100 and Run the scenario (100 users login at the same time, Ramp up = 1) . The Result tree said that 100 users were logged in successfully, but when I check each user in the result, there are a lot of users can not log in the website, they are still at the Login page.

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need 100 accounts to simulate 100 users load. 1 user account is enough. However it **completely depends on your application & your test script design**.

1 of our applications do not support different sessions for the same user account. It will kill old the session. So, If I follow your approach, only the 100th thread will be active. All other user sessions will be destroyed. So I had to create different user accounts.

Even if your application supports this, you need to design your script carefully.

**For ex:** Lets assume your test script - logins to the gmail application, deletes the first email. So, if you are using 100 threads for the same account, you need to ensure that you have 100 emails for the account so that all the threads can have some emails to delete.

When you have rampup as 1 second,

1) You are actually Stress testing the server - Server can not handle this huge load. This could be causing the failure.

2) Considering the above example, when 100 users (but 1 account) login to the application at once, there is a chance that more than 1 thread would try to delete same email which could also cause failure.

So, try to have appropriate rampup period as per your requirements, create more accounts / update test script accordingly.

Comment: Dear Vinoth S,
Thanks for your precious advice,
Yesterday I created 100 user's accounts > put data in CSV file and use the CSV Configuration of Jmeter to run my script.
Tomorrow, I will test with 1000 users, here is my plan:
I will use 11 computers: 1 host, 10 slaves to perform Distributed testing.
At each slave, I will put a CSV file which contains 100 accounts (seperate from 1000 users) and my script.
Then, I will use Host to remote 10 slaves.
Is it a good plan or not??? Thanks and hope you have nice weekend

Comment: @hidalgo Could u find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

generally webapplications generates token (like csrftoken) for each request when we hit the application url for security purpose for the first time in browser. it uses the same token in every subsequent request. but you cannot use the same  token for multiple users as the application will not allow the user to login. We have to dynamoically fetch the authentication token in the first request using post processor and send it dynamically in the subsequent request. hope this helps.

let me  know if this helps.